# solr tries to upgrade my schema to managed

Tags: solr

This is on solr 7.1.0. I have a classic schema, with the proper line in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

However I still get this line in the log:

```
ManagedIndexSchemaFactory The schema has been upgraded to managed,&#8203; but the non-managed schema schema.xml is still loadable. PLEASE REMOVE THIS FILE.
```

And when I inspect that core's schema it's the generic schema, not the one defined in my `schema.xml`.

Comment: Have you removed the existing managed-schema from the directory?

Comment: There was no managed-schema in the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the core you **think** is loading is not the one that that is actually loading. Because:

- Upgraded schema should have been the same as the original one - you are seeing a different one
- You don't see managed-schema in the directory you expect it to be
- You keep getting the message

So, have a look at the overview page of that core and check whether the **instance** directory points to where you expect it to be.

Comment: Thank you, the core directory was right but in my test solr 7.0.0 install, solr expected my config files in `core/`, whereas 7.1.0 expected them in `core/config/`. Looking for `managed-schema` was the key to finding out about the problem though, so thanks a lot !